# How to change the text in textbox depending on another textbox

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript

basically i am creating a simple quiz on flash cs6 using action script 3.0 and i have made the following "prototype" model for calculating the score and giving feedback depending on it:

```
var xx:Number = 0;
button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonCount);
function buttonCount(event:MouseEvent)
{ xx = xx +1;   var xxx:String = String(xx);    score.text = xxx
}

if (score.text == "1"){
    feedback.text == "well done";
}
```

button1 is the correct answer which will increase the score by 1. "1" and "well done" are just examples. score.text is where the score is displayed. and feedback.text is feedback. i plan to use other "else if" to give feedback on different scores. Both the text boxes are dynamic text.

I'm pretty much a noob at JavaScript and i am doing this for an ict project. The 'if' does not work for some reason, however the button1 does increase the value of score.text by one. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
 var xx:Number = 0;
button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonCount);
function buttonCount(event:MouseEvent)
{ xx = xx +1;   var xxx:String = String(xx);    score.text = xxx
}

if (score.text == "1"){
    feedback.text == "well done";
}
```

to

```
    var xx:Number = 0;
    button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonCount);
    function buttonCount(event:MouseEvent)
    { 
if (score.text == "1"){
        feedback.text = "well done";
xx = xx +1;   var xxx:String = String(xx);    score.text = xxx
    }else{
feedback.text = "wrong."
    }

}
```

Basically, I changed `feedback.text == "well done"` to `feedback.text = "well done"`

You only use `==` in conditional statements, and if you're declaring what the text shall be you put `=`.

`==` means if it equals, and = means if it's equalling, so if i say `if(blah=0)` it would be called if i said `blah = 0`, though if i said `if(blah==0)` it would call every time the amount hits 0.

Comment: No prob.  Really needed the rep :P

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your "if" statement executes? I think, the problem is, you never enter this comparison.